# Is there a library for SCNMaterials in swift?

Tags: scenekit

I am pretty new to working with materials in SceneKit, and am finding generating materials pretty difficult. Is there any sort of library of material examples online somewhere? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Because SceneKit has OpenGL roots, you can replicate most simple OpenGL materials in SceneKit. See, for example,  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Every_Material_Known_to_Man and  http://devernay.free.fr/cours/opengl/materials.html.

Simon Gladman has a simple SceneKit material editor on Github that is useful if you're tinkering: https://github.com/FlexMonkey/SceneKitMaterialEditor.

More complicated and realistic looking materials generally require the use of shaders. I'm not aware of a SceneKit shader library.